# Automatic Creating of Views with dropdown on 1:n relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I followed a Tutorial a few weeks ago which shows how to create a simple ASP.NET MVC 3 App (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1).
Now I created another app that is actually doing something very simple, but I cant make Visual Studio 2010 automatically creating a View that shows a selection of the 1:n connection.
The program is a simple News system with a relation NewsEntry.NewsCategory to NewsCategory.ID.

NewsEntry.cs

```
public class NewsEntry
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortText { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UnpublishDate { get; set; }
    public NewsCategory NewsCategory { get; set; }
}
```

NewsDB.cs

```
public class NewsCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<NewsEntry> News { get; set; }
}
```

NewsDB.cs

```
public class NewsDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<NewsEntry> NewsEntry { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewsCategory> NewsCategory { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is what is missing that VS is not creating a view with category in a drop down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It obviously helped to add a NewsCategoryId field:

```
public class NewsEntry
{
    public int NewsEntryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortText { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UnpublishDate { get; set; }
    public int NewsCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual NewsCategory NewsCategory { get; set; }
}
```